# search and replace a string

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

is there a way to search and replace a string using single unix command `grep` recusrsively in multiple directories?
i know it can be done by using the combination of find with other utilities like sed perl etc.but is there a way where we can use only grep for doing this on unix command line?

Comment: Why the constraint to use grep? Getting sed involved will make this much easier imho.

Comment: Indeed. `grep` is for searching only, it simply doesn't *do* replace. `sed` and `perl` are both more appropriate tools for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that only grep would work here; involving sed and other utilities will be much more easier, than just grep

Answer (score 0):

one way, if you have GNU find and bash shell

```
find /path -type f -iname "*.txt" | while read -r FILE
do
    while read -r LINE
    do
       case "$LINE" in
         *WORD_TO_SEARCH* ) LINE=${LINE//WORD_TO_SEARCH/REPLACE};;
       esac
       echo "$LINE" >> temp
    done < "$FILE"
    mv temp "$FILE"
done
```